rclone.conf disappears after running rclone sync command
I am using rclone and I chose AWS as a test environment for a project requiring file synchronization between local devices and cloud. In the present scenario, files are synched between EC2 and S3.
The synch procedure works, but immediately after, the rclone.conf
file seems deleted and I am no longer able to access the EC2 through PuTTY (it says: "server refused keys"). There should be some underneath processes that mess up with keys/config files - but I am not able to identify it/them.
Anyone has encountered (and solved) anything similar?
